# ping operation not permitted

Tags: android, root, ping, icmp

I want to find how many devices connecting the LAN which my android phone connected. 
The easy way is to ping every IP in LAN. (better ideas ?)

It's unwise to use "Runtime.getRuntime.exec" because of starting too many processes.

So I decided to port the ping code and compile it to a library file and then invoke it by JNI from within an Android app.

But when I test this apk on my telephone, "operation not permitted" happened in icmp_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RDM, IPPROTO_ICMP);

This should have root right.

Can anyone has any idea?

Comment: Don't know so much about this, but here's a few ideas. Instead of various programs on a LAN trying to find each other it is better to designate one machine to be a server or hub, and that machine keeps track of all of the "clients" and can send a list of the clients to all of the clients whenever the list changes. For example, in Windows networks there is one server that functions as the "RPC server", and performs this task. That's how Outlook can find the Exchange Server. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759499%28v=ws.10%29.aspx Presumably Linux and Mac systems have similar.